# Google Ad Manager API: Display report results

Tags: php, api, google-ad-manager

I want to display data in my web page from orders of Google Ad Manager via their API using PHP.

If you follow the *[Reporting Basics](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reporting)* page, you will end up downloading the report you want, but I need to display the data taken from Ad Manager directly to my page.

I have searched everywhere to find a solution to this problem, but I cannot find anything but reading the downloaded file, which adds tons of '*page load time*' to my web page.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So there are 3 cases you need to think about:

1. If you are not building a report, just downloading it, check the size obviously. If it is too large, then it's all about your connection, also caching on a website server can help.
2. If you are building the report, it is pretty much normal to wait for it to be built then download it.
3. If you want data from the API, you can get it directly from there - take a look at the Report service - https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v201902/ReportService
   There is a very helpful PHP script (and other languages) that can help you setup authentication and a token, and yes if you have access to your Linux server you can set it up on your website probably - though be careful. Here is the link - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/ and take a look at other languages if you don't like PHP https://github.com/googleads/

Answer (score -1):

If you are concerned about the loading time when pulling data from the API, an easier way around would be to download and storing data to your database in advance, let's say every hour (or less, depending on your needs), and when page is loaded retrieve the data from your database instead of getting it in real-time from API. There is anyway 15 minutes delay on the API.